# Ошибка "can't open file 'm': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Что нужно сделать, чтобы начать работать с Google Assistant?
Работаю по [этому мануалу](https://webcheerz.com/install-google-assistant-in-windows-10/).

На `py m pip install google-assistant-sdk[samples]`процесс встает:

> ```
> C:\Users\User01>py m pip install google-assistant-sdk[samples]
> C:\Users\User01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe:
> can't open file 'm': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
> ```

Линк:
[image: Линк]

Что делать?

Жду фитбэк, заранее спасибо.

**P.S.:** Также непонятно какие папки, где нужно дополнительно создавать и тп.

Comment: Привет, жду ваших комментариев. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В статье опечатка.
Правильный код следующий (видно по скриншоту из статьи):

```
py -m pip install google-assistant-sdk[samples]
```

Comment: Приветствую! Не работает полностью, у Вас есть правильный мануал?